# What are different between Regression testing and test re running in Quality assurance?

Tags: testing

I'm a beginner of software testing and I'm referring about testing type. Then I have met this question.

Answer (score 0):

Regression testing is re-running functional and non-functional tests to ensure that previously developed and tested software still performs after a change. If not, that would be called a regression.

Changes that may require regression testing include bug fixes, software enhancements, configuration changes, and even substitution of electronic components. 
As regression test suites tend to grow with each found defect, test automation is frequently involved. Sometimes a change impact analysis is performed to determine an appropriate subset of tests.

So with that being said, regression actively means re-running the test suite you had before the enhancements were done.

Answer (score 0):

Regression Testing is a done to check whether the bug fix or any enhancement in our code doesn't affect the entire code,This is probably done in last phase.

Whereas, Re-Testing or you say test-re-running is done when a particular test fails and the bug is solved to just check whether the particular test passes or not and the bug is fixed or not. This is done after each bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

Regression testing is a form of software testing that confirms or denies a software’s functionality after the software undergoes changes

Retesting is testing of a particular bug after it has been fixed.